# How to open the a .CTO file for updating the content using VScode?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am working on creating a sample hyperledger composer solution and created a skeleton business network using below command.

yo hyperledger-composer:businessnetwork

But I am not sure how to open the model file "org.example.mynetwork.cto" to edit.

Invoked my composer playground installed on my mac but its doesn't show the skeleton network I created.

So where to open the business network files to edit? I want to edit my .cto, script and .acl files.

Answer (score 1):

actually the `.cto` file is the plain text file, and also the .js(script), .acl(Adding access control), you can open these files as normal, and here is a good [toturial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5wZvmZGuAY) from IBMBlockchain can demo how to edit those files.

Answer (score 1):

Using yo hyperledger-composer:businessnetwork correctly will generate a folder with the same name as the network name you added. It will be generated where you are in the terminal. 
For example if your terminal is opened in desktop `admin@admin:~/Desktop$` the folder will be created on Desktop.

Inside that folder you will find your `.acl` file.

Inside "Model" folder you will find your `.cto` file .

Inside "lib" will be your `script.js`(Transaction Logic file).

This is assuming you have downloaded & Install Hyperledger Composer Properly
If not Install Prereqs using this
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html
and hyperledger composer from
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

They also have tutorial which will help you out.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to edit the file. I didn't realize that and was thinking I would be able to see the files inside the composer playground. Yes, I installed hyperledger composer already and trying to create a solution. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: No Problem @Elayabharathi!